# NServiceBus setting time to be received

Tags: nservicebus, esb

Can you set TTBR (Time To Be Received) on a message sent using NServiceBus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely - put the TimeToBeReceived attribute on the relevant message class. Here's an example setting it to 10 minutes:

```
[TimeToBeReceived("00:10:00")]
```

Comment: Thank you for the information! I've got one quick follow-up question: can client override that attribute programmatically? 

Mine is a scenario in which client sends notifications about its status to the server at a given interval. If the interval is set to 10 minutes then I want TimeToBeReceived be set to 10 minut because only the latest status is of importance. It would be good if the interval configuration was up to a client.

Comment: Why would the server want it to be any other value then?

Comment: Well, it is up to the client how often it wants to notify server about its status. Maybe that's not the most important feature but definitely some way of setting different TimeToBeReceived value for test/production environment would be of value to me.

Comment: Michael, TimeToBeReceived really is only relevant for production environments. Under regular conditions, messages will be delivered close to instantly - it's only under failure conditions that it starts to have an effect.